# MySQL Error: ReverseEngineerTable: Skipping Index table.column on a LONGCHAR column

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, migration

I'm migrating my Access database tables to be hosted online with MySQL. When I use MySQL Workbench to migrate it over, it throws a number of errors during the `Reverse Engineer` source phase:

```
WARNING: Migration: reverseEngineerTable: Skipping index tblProducts.txtContractType on a LONGCHAR column
```

I am unsure about what steps to take to resolve this. Errors are coming from tables that allow multiple values, allow value list edits, and whose row source is a value list of multiple options. Is it not possible to migrate columns that allow multiple values?

Comment: That's indeed not possible. Have a look at [Access multivalue field convert to MS SQL](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/access-multivalue-field-convert-to-ms-sql/05e4ebe9-d919-44c6-bf76-efe47e0d5cae)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? Did you make any research? Check @Rene comment.

Comment: Please @Rene, post your comment as answer.

Comment: Thanks @Rene for the insight. New to MySQL, so anything helps!

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more specific in the future, but looks like I got the answer I was looking for. @DavidGarcíaBodego